# Is it safe to use pthread_mutex_* in single thread/process mode?

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a program that can run in single thread/process mode, and multiple thread/process mode,

I have many code like this:

```
if(global.multiple) pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
updateSth();
if(global.multiple) pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

where `global.multiple` indicates whether the program is running on multiple threads/processes or not.

I'm wondering is `if(global.multiple)` redundant?

Comment: It's an extra test.  Making the call would be fairly swift; it won't run into locks if the process is single threaded.  Measure and see whether it makes a detectable (let alone significant) difference.  Gut feel, it would be simpler to eliminate `global.multiple` and simply always use the mutex calls, and the cost would be minimal.

Comment: So if performance is not priority, it is safe to just remove it?

Comment: Note that it is a pTHREAD_mutex, not a Interprocess Communication. It only works with threads, not with processes.

Comment: Yes, if performance is not the most critical issue, then removing the test of `global.multiple` is safe.  If performance is critical, it would be a good idea to demonstrate that the test does provide a worthwhile performance gain.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you, got it

Comment: @mch if mutex is in shared memory, will it work?

Comment: See POSIX on [`pthread_mutexattr_getpshared()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html) etc. for process-shared mutexes.